# Resource for learning Category of Modules

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, modules, book-recommendation

I'm studying Module Theory. And I want to learn Category theory but for now i need to learn just some basic Category only for understanding Category of R-modules. For example I'm curently struggling with pruducts and coproducts of modules. I find it in Saunder Mac Lane's Category textbook but it looks so complicated cause i don't know that much Category Theory. I think i should study first. So can anyone suggest a textbook, lecture notes ect. for understanding Category of modules.

Comment: So what about [existing suggestions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation+modules) is lacking?  This seems like a duplicate of most similar questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of resources you might consider are Anderson-Fuller "Rings and Categories of Modules"(AF) and Herrlich-Strecker "Category Theory"(HS). I have tried using Mac Lane's book as a reference from time to time, without much success. It is considered a standard, given the reputation of the author, but it has often left me mystified. If I had Mac Lane"s almost encyclopedic knowledge of mathematics I might have had more success. HS is written from the perspective of providing motivation for the concepts being introduced, something I found more in line with what I needed.

AF is a very accessible book and is reasonably self-contained. In the author blurb on the back of the book, it is mentioned that Fuller has published on categorical and homological aspects of rings and their modules. I refer to it often. I hope this helps at least a little bit.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate. (And thank you for trying to understand my broken english)

Comment: @Hector - You're welcome. And your English is just fine.